# What is the difference between recursion and induction?

Tags: definition

What is the difference between recursion and induction? I have heard those terms used interchangeably, but I was wondering if there is a difference between them, and if so, what the difference is.

Comment: To proceed recursively is essentially to work backwards, while proceeding inductively is to essentially work forwards, in some sense. At least, that's my understanding of it.

Comment: Probably, main is which definitions and from where you take? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction maybe is not good source, but gives some impression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my experience:

- "Recursion" is a way of *defining* some mathematical *object* (including a function or computation whose definition involves a recursive algorithm);
- "Induction" is a way of *proving* some mathematical *statement*.

Extremely often, if a mathematical statement is made about a recursively-defined object, then the proof of that statement will involve induction.

For example, the definition of the [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) is a recursive definition. The proof of the assertion that the $n$th Fibonacci number is at most $2^n$ is an inductive proof.

Comment: I did searches on Math Overflow for “inductive definition” and “recursive definition”.  There were 43 and 65 respectively.

Comment: That is my usage and what I would call careful usage, but the OP is not wrong in saying that the terms are often used interchangeably.  When asked I certainly recommend that usage, but that ship has probably sailed.